# Voting up a Youtube Comment (Externaly)

Tags: php

I'm trying to vote up a youtube comment,

due sending (in one session)

> session_token=MYSESSIONID

to

> http://www.youtube.com/comment_voting?a=1&id=COMMENTID&video_id=VIDEOID&old_vote=0

but it fails,
and Im using this form to send post request:

```
<FORM action="http://www.youtube.com/comment_voting?a=1&id=COMMENTID&video_id=VIDEOID&old_vote=0" method="post">
    <P>
              <INPUT type="text" id="session_token">
  <INPUT type="submit" value="Send">
    </P>
 </FORM>
```

Im not sure If Im sending post request in good way (After I click Send it sends requests and displays Error).

If its any small error on my sending way, and sorry for my bad english, thanks.

Comment: Why would you expect this to work in the first place? Looking at the YouTube website, the voting button is implemented using AJAX somehow, not as a form post. You could try sniffing the network traffic to see what really gets sent and duplicate that somehow.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, reason is because was working in the past, approximately in the same way.

Im checking traffic from firefox live http headers but Im doing something wrong

Comment: I'm probably going WAY on a limb here, but the name "old_vote" might mean it was a way that was going to be deprecated. Possibly kept there as the big YouTube redesign was being rolled out, then turned off after the rollout completed. It certainly doesn't seem like Google wants you to be able (or cares about you being able to) to vote on comments without using a web browser, seeing as the functionality isn't part of the API as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yes also old_vote is have dynamic value but that is crawled too
and i saw couple of peoples doing this too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YouTube disabled this feature. You can not vote up outside of YouTube. I have tried looking for a source to prove it, but I could not find anything.

Comment: Aha I see, I tried and tried but not working, now the only way is with client side bots that are working good except that a little slowly